# String assignment operator C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reference, operators

I am looking through some code for the assignment operator of the string class and there are some concepts that I do no understand.

1) The argument is a constant but the value ends up getting changed, I thought that constants cannot get changed?

2) You pass the address of the string argument and then in the if statement you again access the address, couldn't you leave out the Ampersand since the address should already be accessed just using "right"?

```
String& String::operator=(const String& right) //why is const passed is a new value gets assigned?
  {
     if (this != &right) // Cant this be if(this != right)
        {
           delete[] buffer; // Get rid of old buffer len = right.length();
           buffer = new char[len + 1];
           for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
             buffer[i] = right[i];
            buffer[len] = '\0';
        }  
     return *this;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post separate question in the future.

In (1), you're confusing the two sides of the assignment. The *right* side is const. `a=b` definitely does not change **b**.

(2) You pass an expression, not an address. `right` is a *reference* to that expression. `this` on the other hand is a pointer. Check your book, this is basic C++.

Answer (score 0):

The string is passed in as a const *reference*, not as a const pointer.  Hence the check has to be `this != &right` to get a pointer-to-pointer comparison.

Comment: Isn't a pointer just a memory address? So wouldn't this != right just be comparing two memory addresses?

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the String that `operator=` was called on.  `right` is a *const reference* to a String.  So `this != right` would be attempting to compare a pointer-to-String to const String.  You have to use `&` to get the address of right

Comment: isn't the address passed in the argument though? Not just a string but the address?

Comment: Technically under the hood, the const reference to a String is probably passed as a pointer.  However, in the function, a reference is treated exactly the same as an object (aka pretend the function is `operator=(String right)`

Comment: So could I then pass (const string right) as an argument and have the if statement as if(else != &right). Would that work?

Comment: You then pass by value and not by reference, so it will make a copy of right to pass into the method.  So technically that would work, but you probably don't want to do it since it causes an unnecessary copy

Comment: The "unnecessary" copy would make the `this != &right` comparison pointless! A copy has a unique address. The test `this!= &right` catches the `a=a` case. This is important because the code above calls `delete[] this->buffer` before copying `right.buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are passing in a const reference, it means you can't change the `right` argument but you can change the contents of `this`.

2) `this` is a pointer. `right` is a reference. They are not the same and so you can't compare directly. You can get the address of the reference using `&right`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the assignment operator on two strings, A and B, e.g., A=B, the string B is passed in as a const reference.  The string A is what is being modified.

In the line this != &right, we are comparing this (a pointer to the string on the LHS of the = sign) to &right (the address of the string on the RHS of the equals sign).  It would not make sense to compare a pointer with a string, as would happen if we used this != right.

Comment: If the argument is (const String& right) doesn't that mean that "right" is passed as an address? So when you write this != right wouldn't you be comparing the address the pointer "this" points to and the address "right" points to? I feel like saying &right in the if statement is redundant to get the address since an address is already passed as an arguement?

Comment: I think you are confusing an important distinction between references and pointers.  When the argument is listed as (const String& right), it means that right is passed as a reference -- not a pointer. Hence, anywhere right appears in the function, it is treated as a string object (although it is a reference to the string passed in).  Hence, in the program, to obtain the memory address of right, we must write &right (this gets the address of a reference, which is the same as the address of the original string being referenced).